# Searching JSON for a variable then returning the name of the parent tag

Tags: python, json, parsing

So i'm trying to get the name of a tag parenting a tag that includes my search variable that was defined earlier in my loop. The parent tag is always different.
Heres the structure of the json im working with.

```json
{
  "Data" : {
    "Site" : {
      "RandomID I don't want" : {
        "Service" : {
          "RandomID I want" : "Namers"
        },
        "title" : "(The string im searching for)"
      }
```

and so on and so on...

So I tried narrowing my results

```
firebase = urlopen('firebase.json').read().decode('utf-8')
aniIndex = json.loads(firebase)
aniIndex2 = aniIndex.get("Data")
aniIndex3 = aniIndex2.get("Site")
print(aniIndex3) #Returns the section I want to search into
```

Now my issue is how I search into the tags since the next tag is a random name. So I thought if I could search for the text of "Title" and check for it's parent tag. I've tried to find a way to do this but none really work for the situation I have

Edit: I messed up the Json structure, Fixed (im sorry it's like 5 am)

Comment: you can use something like `.keys()`which gives you available keys for a json if there are some.
Eg `json["data"].keys()` will return the keys if json["data"] is an inner dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bit of code that seems to do what you want. If you need all the items with a `title` tag, then exclude the `break` statement and do something with the items you want inside the loop.

```
data = {
    "Data": {
        "Site": {
            "RandomID I don't want": {
                "Service": {
                    "RandomID I want": "Namers"
                },
                "title": "(The string im searching for)"
            }
        }
    }
}

for v in data["Data"]["Site"].values():
    if "title" in v:
        if v["title"] == "(The string im searching for)":
            id_i_want = list(v["Service"].keys())[0]
            break

print("Id I want: '{}'".format(id_i_want))
```

output:

```
Id I want: 'RandomID I want'
```

Comment: This returns the id, however it doesn't select by the string im searching with. It just returns the first occurence of "Service". Refer to the comment I left on Chris's answer.

Comment: @Soul_kept I edited the code to search for the string, and return the id.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't call this as the best solution, but here's a working one:

Suppose your json looks like this:

```
print(d)
{
  "Data": {
    "Site": {
      "(RandomId)": {
        "Title": "Thing"
      },
      "(Text I want)": {
        "Title": "(The string i'm searching for)"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then with two recursive functions:

```
def find_children(dic, value):
    child, grandchild = '', ''
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            child, grandchild = find_children(v, value)
            if child:
                break
        else:
            if value in v:
                return k, v
    return child, grandchild

def find_parent(dic, children):
    parents = ''
    for k, v in dic.items():
        if isinstance(v, dict):
            if children[0] in v.keys() and children[1] in v.values():
                return k
            else:
                parents = find_parent(v, children)
    return parents
```

You can find:

```
find_parent(d, find_children(d, "i'm searching"))
# '(Text I want)'
find_parent(d, find_children(d, "Thing"))
# '(RandomId)'
```

Comment: I might just be missing something but it returns this error "isinstance() arg 2 must be a type or tuple of types"

Comment: If you copy pasted the answer, the only explanation is that `dict` has been assigned by something else, and thus not a python literal anymore.

Comment: Your solution worked for the original json but I formatted it incorrectly, I apologize for the confusion, but I've just edited the json to the correct thing

Comment: @Soul_kept Are you sure the edited json is correct? By the look of it, the _RandomID I want_ is not a parent tag of _title_; it became a neighbor's (_Service_) child tag, which is almost impossible to trace from _The string im searching for_

Comment: Yes it's correct, that's my issue. I don't know if it was possible.

Comment: I want to search the json for the "String im searching for" then return "Random Id I want"

Comment: I need the information under "Service" however there are multiples of them, so @Chris I need to check with "Title" to match it with "name" which was defined earlier in my code. Then after checking if "Title" matches "name" return the "Random ID I want" under service. I also can't rely on "Namers" since that is also pretty much random.